# Redirect Stderr in micropython?

Tags: python, embedded-linux, micropython, openmv

Using micro python I am trying to redirect stderr to a file however I dont have access to the run command on the board so I cannot do any shell redirect commands like `>> > |`.  I'm curious if there is a way to do this in Micropython.

I've tried

```
import sys

sys.stdout = open('out.txt', 'w')
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
```

however

https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=2091 <- this discussion mentions that it is not a method supported.  Im curious if y'all have any ideas.  Most my googling leads itself to just python instead of micropython.

but get an error stating module has no attribute named stdout
thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the script that I have been using to log console output to file

```
import io, os

class logToFile(io.IOBase):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def write(self, data):
        with open("logfile.txt", mode="a") as f:
            f.write(data)
        return len(data)
# Begin loging to file
os.dupterm(logToFile())

# Stop loging to file
os.dupterm(None)
```

Comment: side note - I tried this. It seems to have a side effect of really slowing down the serial monitor. At least on a esp32-cam board Not sure if you experienced that.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it, but the [doc](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/usys.html) suggests you can do this if you use `usys` rather than `sys`. The `open()` will actually call [uio.open()](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/uio.html).

Comment: good find.  ill take a look when I can and if it works out I will verify the usage here